# How to show that left rotation is inverse of right rotation?

Tags: graph, tree, avl-tree

I know this question is a simple question. But I am facing difficulty in grasping the concepts of AVL trees.

> How to show that the double rotations in AVL trees are inverse of each
>   other ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: All you have to do is to show that if you do the two rotations one after the other, you get the tree that you started with. This can be done pictorially, using pen and paper.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I tried the same before. It is not coming. Do we need to rotate with respect to root or a particular labeled node while taking the inverse ?